# ls command in a variable to display in dialog checklist and processing of the selected option

Tags: shell-script, directory, dialog

i just started shell programming and i can't get the following problem to work.

I want that all directorys, from a defined directory (e.g.. /var), are displayed in dialog checklist. I also want that in the selected folders, get stored a previously defined variable (in every folder the same).

Does anyone have a solution for the problem?

edit//

solution

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/var"
function cho () {
options=$(ls "$DIR" | awk '{print $1, FNR, "off"}')
cmd=(dialog --title Menu --stdout \
      --separate-output \
      --checklist "Select options:" 22 76 16)
choices=$("${cmd[@]}" ${options})
check
}
function check () {
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   if [ -z "$choices" ]; then
      dialog --title Menu --msgbox "No option selected!" 5 28
      dialog --clear
      cho
else
   for choice in $choices
   do
   echo "$choice"
   done
fi
else
  clear && echo ""Cancel...
fi
}
cho
```

Comment: Are you expecting a _graphical_ pop-up dialog box?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the selected folders, get stored a previously defined variable"?

Comment: yes, it needs to be a graphical dialog box.
in the script, which i m working on, there is first a message box - this text is saved in a variable - second what kind of message - info, attention,... also saved in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

dir='/'

select name in $( find "$dir" -type d ! -name "$dir" -maxdepth 1 ); do
    if [ -z "$name" ]; then
        echo 'error' >&2
    else
        break
    fi
done

printf 'User picked "%s"\n' "$name"
```

This is a simple shell script that lists the directories under `$dir` and presents a menu to the user to pick one of them from.

The selected entry will be stored in `$name`.

Testing it:

```
$ sh script.sh
 1) /altroot                             7) /root
 2) /bin                                 8) /sbin
 3) /dev                                 9) /tmp
 4) /etc                                10) /usr
 5) /home                               11) /var
 6) /mnt                                12) /tmp_mnt
#? q
error
#? 0
error
#? 9
User picked "/tmp"
```

This script will probably fail if any of the found directory names contains unusual characters, such as newlines.